# How to create the radio buttons for enable and disable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable and disable mailer notification through radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470934/how-to-enable-and-disable-mailer-notification-through-radio-buttons)

I am making an application in which when the user create ,update or delete the user it will get a notification mail.Now what i want is at the time of creation of user it will be asked to the user that you want the notification mail through radio buttons the user can enable it or disable.
Now can anyone tell me how to create these two radio buttons???
Any help would be appreciated..

Thank you

Comment: you should try it yourself. stackoverflow is not for getting whole solutions, more for getting help if you have a specific question to a problem..

Comment: dude,i am not asking for the whole solution i have made the radio buttons but i just couldn't read the value th buttons....\

Comment: then feel free to post your code

Comment: okkk.....and here is my code

Answer (score 0):

This is my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
# GET /users
# GET /users.json


def index
@users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @users }
end
end

# GET /users/1
# GET /users/1.json
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

# GET /users/new
# GET /users/new.json
def new
@user = User.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
   if @user.Notification then
     UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  end

    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
    format.json { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PUT /users/1
# PUT /users/1.json
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|


    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /users/1
# DELETE /users/1.json
def destroy
@user = User.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.destroy
    # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver

    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
    format.json { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

end
```

And this is my _form.html

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :login %><br />
<%= f.text_field :login %>
</div>

<%= f.radio_button(:Notification, "True") %>
<%= f.label(:Notification_True, "True") %>
<br />
<%= f.radio_button(:Notification, "False") %>
<%= f.label(:Notification_False, "False") %>
<div class="actions">

<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And i have add the Notification attribute to the my model User which is of Boolean type for the radio buttons.